# MMC not starting on Window Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

I have Window 2003 server with AD installed. The file server is used to share the folder across network.

However after 1 hour suddenly I can't access my share - it asks me the password and then when I enter it it does not allow me, and say `access denied`.

When I try to open `mmc.exe` on server it says:

```
The application has failed to start because MS.dll was not loaded
```

How can I fix this problem? Can I re-install MMC?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's MS.dll and not msoe.dll or something else? All I could find with ms.dll is that it could be a bug
http://www.threatexpert.com/files/ms.dll.html

Comment: yes its MS.dll , i have attached the image as well , What should i do to rectify thatbug or threat